# how to convert scalar into inline function sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to convert scalar into inline function

my scalar function

```
    create function [dbo].[fun_functional_score] (@phy_id varchar(20))
    returns  varchar(50)

    as
    begin 

    declare @level_initial int, @level_current int

    -- initial functional score
    set @level_initial=(SELECT pflag.fun_level
    FROM tbl_phy_demographic_details as [phy] 
        inner join tbl_all_purple_flag_level as [pflag] on phy.Demographic_id=pflag.Id 
    WHERE phy.Physicion_id= @phy_id
        and pflag.visited_count in (select MAX(visited_count)-1 from tbl_all_purple_flag_level group by id ))


    -- current functional score
    set @level_current=(SELECT pflag.fun_level
    FROM tbl_phy_demographic_details as [phy] 
        inner join tbl_all_purple_flag_level as [pflag] on phy.Demographic_id=pflag.Id 
    WHERE phy.Physicion_id=@phy_id
        and pflag.visited_count in (select MAX(visited_count) from tbl_all_purple_flag_level group by id ))


-- current functional scor

--set @level_current=(SELECT pflag.fun_level

--  FROM tbl_phy_demographic_details as [phy] 



    --to calculate functional score
    declare @fun_level varchar(20),@result varchar(50)

    set  @fun_level=@level_current-@level_initial;

     if @fun_level = 0   set @result='Maintained' 
    if @fun_level = '-1'  set @result='Minor Improvement' 
    if @fun_level = '-2'  set @result='Moderate Improvement' 
    if @fun_level = '-3'  set @result='Significant Improvement' 
    if @fun_level =  '-4'  set @result='Substantial Improvement' 
    if @fun_level =  '1'  set @result='Minor Reduction' 
    if @fun_level =  '2'  set @result='Moderate Reduction' 
    if @fun_level =  '3'  set @result='Significant Reduction' 
    if @fun_level =  '4'  set @result='Substantial Reduction' 




     return @result

     end
```

it is possible ?

Comment: Please don't tag SQL Server questions with [tag:mysql]. "MySQL" does not mean "my current SQL Server problem"...

Comment: are you trying you asking the same question that you have posted earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046294/how-to-return-multilpe-values-from-function-sql-server ?

Comment: yes that has some error this is updated code. now i need to convert into inline function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function is not considered to be "inline" if it has a return statement. I don't 100% know what you're going for, but you could rewrite your attempted rewrite like this and have it be considered inline:

```
SELECT CASE @level_current-@level_initial
  WHEN '0' THEN 'Maintained'
  WHEN '-1' THEN 'Minor Improvement'
  WHEN '-2' THEN 'Moderate Improvement'
  ....
  ELSE 'some default value' END AS ReturnValue
```

Essentially in order for a function to be inline, it must be a single SQL statement.

**EDIT**

I don't believe you can create an inline scalar value function (someone please correct me if I'm wrong). An inline function must be a table value function (though the table can consist of a single column and a single row).

Comment: I made a couple of edits (including aliasing the column from the SELECT statement).

Answer (score 0):

```
create function [dbo].[fun_functional_score] (@phy_id varchar(20))
returns table
as
return (
  WITH
  t1(fun_level) AS (
    SELECT
    ( 
      SELECT pflag.fun_level -- current functional score
      FROM tbl_phy_demographic_details as [phy] 
          inner join tbl_all_purple_flag_level as [pflag] on phy.Demographic_id=pflag.Id 
      WHERE phy.Physicion_id= @phy_id
          and pflag.visited_count in (select MAX(visited_count) from tbl_all_purple_flag_level group by id )
    ) -
    (     
      SELECT pflag.fun_level -- initial functional score
      FROM tbl_phy_demographic_details as [phy] 
          inner join tbl_all_purple_flag_level as [pflag] on phy.Demographic_id=pflag.Id 
      WHERE phy.Physicion_id=@phy_id
          and pflag.visited_count in (select MAX(visited_count)-1 from tbl_all_purple_flag_level group by id )
    )
  ),
  t2(fun_level, result) AS (
    SELECT  '0', 'Maintianed'              UNION ALL
    SELECT '-1', 'Minor Improvement'       UNION ALL
    SELECT '-2', 'Moderate Improvement'    UNION ALL
    SELECT '-3', 'Significant Improvement' UNION ALL
    SELECT '-4', 'Substantial Improvement' UNION ALL
    SELECT  '1', 'Minor Reduction'         UNION ALL
    SELECT  '2', 'Moderate Reduction'      UNION ALL
    SELECT  '3', 'Significant Reduction'   UNION ALL
    SELECT  '4', 'Substantial Reduction'
  )
  SELECT result FROM t2 INNER JOIN t1 ON t1.fun_level = t2.fun_level
)
```

Ideally, `t2` should be a real table in the database and not hardcoded values buried in a function.

Comment: error "This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression." what to do help me...